# How to implement an array data structure from scratch in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, implementation

I've used arrays in python (both as list and array.array) but I was wondering how can I implement a data structure like an array in Python. The following is my implementation after looking at implementations done in other languages. Please let me know of improvements.

```
class my_array:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.data = {}

    def get(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
    
    def push(self, item):
        self.data[self.length] = item
        self.length += 1
        return self.data
    
    def pop(self):
        last_item = self.data[self.length - 1]
        del self.data[self.length-1]
        self.length -= 1
        return last_item
    
    def insert(self, index, item):
        self.data[index] = item
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you're just looking for suggestions and this code works, it's probably off-topic for the site. In any case, implementing an array with a dict (hashing, lots of overhead) pretty much defeats the purpose of arrays (speed, simplicity, locality). Instead of a dict, I'd use a list which makes more sense for a series of items indexed from `0..n`, at which point, well, you're using a Python list... An actual array/list is [more complicated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) than this "reinventing the wheel" might lead you to believe.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! You're right, I tried it using the list but it just felt like you stated. My objective in implementing array is just to understand it better. While a suggestion on my code is welcome, I was curious on how python did it. Thanks for pointing me to the resource.